# change applicationcontext from in code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I have a little problem. I hope someone can help me.

I'm developping an application for my thesis.
Now I have an application-context.properties.txt where I define:

```
host= (ip address)
port=8080
```

Now this is static and I change the ip address to the server I want to connect to.
But this isn't verry usefull for the user because he can't access that file.

Now is my question can I change this host ip address from in my flex code? And how do I do that.

Hope someone can help me.

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Comment: I am not familiar with that file.  Googling it... Is this a Spring Actionscript project?  If so/not, that type of info might be useful.

Comment: yes it's a spring actionscrip project...had to mention it, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Configurations i.e services.xml embeds at compile time, this blog

[Externalizing Service Configuration using BlazeDS and LCDS](http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/03/externalizing-service-configuration-using-blazeds-and-lcds/)

pointed towards way to Externalizing Service Configuration,

hopes that works,

Comment: thank you for the response but it's not quit what I'm searching for. It's a textfile that I want to change. In that textfile i have only 2 line: hoste=....and port=8080. When I start the application I want to let the user put in an IP address that has to be written away to that text file.

Comment: Are you wants to write in file From Flex, if so call java from you client and pass values and let java do it for you :) hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, the `FlexXMLApplicationContext` is just one example of an application context.  Possibly, you can derive from it or the `XMLApplicationContext` to allow for runtime changes to configuration variables, if the context class doesn't support it already?

You won't be able to change the value in the XML file itself, since it is a compiled resource, but you should be able to extend SpringAS to do what you want at runtime.